# Am I doing this prototype correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, oop, prototype

How do I make these two alert calls pop up?  I feel like I did it right but for some reason, nothing happens in my browser.  I'm guessing I shouldn't have `onclick="isSalaryZeroOrLess();greaterThan()"` on the same line but I'm not so sure.  I just want to use prototypes so I can get my practice in.  I don't want to use boring old functions.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

**Here is the file `gameTime.html`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WOMP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gameTime.css">
</head>     
<body>
    <form class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" name="formHandler" id="handle">
        <div id="allFields">
            <div class="moveUsername">
                <h1>(All numbers inputted will be assumed that it's in dollars)</h1>
                <label for="usr">What's your annual salary?</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="salary" placeholder="What's your annual salary?" required="required">  
            </div>

            <div class="ageMovement">
                <label for="usr">How much do you spend every month on bills?</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="monthlyBills" name="ageChecker" placeholder="How much do you spend every month on bills?" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="emailMovement">
                <label for="usr">How much do you spend when going out?</label>
                <input type="field" class="form-control" id="goingOut" name="emailChecker" placeholder="How much do you spend when going out?" required="required"> 
            </div> 
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="isSalaryZeroOrLess();greaterThan()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gameTime.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the file `gameTime.js`:**

```
 function Finance(salary, fixedExpense, variableExpense) {
    this.salary = salary;
    this.fixedExpense = fixedExpense;
    this.variableExpense = variableExpense;
    this.isSalaryZeroOrLess = function() {
        var s = parseInt(document.getElementById("salary").value);

        if(s <= 0) {
            alert("No money");
        }
    }
}



 Finance.prototype.greaterThan = function() {
    var s = parseInt(document.getElementById("salary").value);
    var userSalary = s / 12;

    if(userSalary > 30000) {
        alert("works!");
    }
}

var fin = new Finance(1000,1000,1000);
```

**Here is the error:**

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: isSalaryZeroOrLess is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (gameTime.html:28)
gameTime.html:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: isSalaryZeroOrLess is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (gameTime.html:28)
gameTime.html:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: isSalaryZeroOrLess is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (gameTime.html:28)
gameTime.html:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: isSalaryZeroOrLess is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (gameTime.html:28)
```

Comment: `Finance` is a role of `Class` so that you must new a instance then use it.

Comment: How shall I do that?  I'm not quite sure how to begin :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it looks like you have not created an object of the Finance.
You can do this then it will work.

```
  var fin = new Finance(1000,1000,1000);
```

After you have defined greaterThan function. Then in onclick you can do this.

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="fin.isSalaryZeroOrLess();fin.greaterThan()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did what you said, but my browser's still not responsive (no alerts popping up) when I click submit.

Comment: I'm getting no errors in the console, I just took a look.

Comment: Wait scratch that.  The "no money" alert works.  The other alert doesn't.

Comment: I guess if your "no money" works then obviously other alert won't show for same value in salary.

Comment: Oh ok, I see.  Take a look at my edited gameTime.js code.  Why won't this code work for the "works!" alert?  I could've sworn it would.

Comment: The value in 'userSalary ' must be greater than 30000 for alert to popup according to your code.

Comment: Yeah I do input numbers which'll make userSalary > 30000 but it still won't work.  I thought that was the most straight forward code I wrote throughout this program, but I guess not :(

Answer (score 0):

You did not use your Finance method anywhere.
First, initialize your Finance object somewhere.

```
var finance = new Finance(your_inputs);
```

Change the onclick of your button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="finance.isSalaryZeroOrLess();finance.greaterThan()">Submit</button>
```